# Flipped Range/Slider input html

Tags: html, slider, range

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
so eg. it starts from max to low (left to right):

---------------------||---------------------

100__________50__________20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/maky5cj6/18/) Link.

**HTML Part:**

```
<input id="slider2" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="50" value="0" >
<input id="rangeValue2" type="text" size="2">
```

**JavaScript Part:**

```
var max_range = 100;
var range_element = document.getElementById("rangeValue2");
var range_input_element = document.getElementById("slider2");
range_element.value = max_range - range_input_element.value;
document.getElementById("slider2").onchange=function(){
    range_element.value = max_range - range_input_element.value;
};
```

**Note:** Max range should be same in HTML and JavaScript.
Like in html it is set as `max="100"` and in JavaScript it is set as `var max_range = 100;`

Comment: thanks but I want the min and max switched, so its like descending slider

Comment: @alital I have updated the code. And also check out the JSFiddle link which is also updated.